# What is this error 7 with google-cast sample ios/application?

Tags: ios, google-cast

I downloaded the chromecast ios sample and when I connect the sample application to chromecast, it give the following error:

`error domain=com.google.GCKError code=7 "The operation couldn't be completed. (com.google.GCKError error 7.)"`

Do you know why?

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error message while testing the "CastHelloText-ios" sample provided by Google on GitHub.

First I checked all the required steps described by Google were ok:

- In your cast developer console: check your Chromecast has the status "Ready for Testing" otherwise [register it](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration#RegisterDevice).
- host the receiver somewhere on the web and note the URL
- in the cast developer console, declare a new app with a custom receiver and fill the URL of your receiver. Save it and note the **application ID**.
- fill this **application ID** in the controller of your iOS app: static NSString *const kReceiverAppID = @"1234ABCD";
- make sure that your chromecast has the option "Send this Chromecast's serial number to Google when checking for updates" is ticked (in the iOS app it's in the General section of your device)

Finally I solved the issue by **rebooting the chromecast**:

- Run the Chromecast iOS app from Google, click on your chromecast device, click on General and click on the red button "Reboot".

For information, I've performed this reboot after reading the note of this [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver):

> If you wish to verify that your published application is working properly, you can manually restart your Google Cast device to force a load of new configuration data.

PS: 
 - to reboot your chromecast you can use any chromecast app provided by Google (iOS, Android, MAC, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

GCKErrorCodeApplicationNotFound - Typically this error will occur if either your device doesn't have [x] send my serial # to Google set, or your AppID is incorrect.

We'll try to get the docs updated shortly.

Answer (score 2):

For test this app you will need to change this line

```
[self.deviceManager launchApplication:kReceiverAppID];
```

To use default applicationID:

```
[self.deviceManager launchApplication:kGCKMediaDefaultReceiverApplicationID];
```

Or you need to create a development account and to change kReceiverAppID with your AppID.

And if you have an another error, you can to check the GCKError.h class, there has all error codes possible with explanation

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case seems like the Chromecast still associated with the old Application ID. It worked fine after restarting the device.